# Altering the structure of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the following

```
    Name  Salary  Company   Dept
     ABC   1000    xyz       pqr
     ABC2  1001    xyz       pqrs
     ABC3  1002    xyzt      pqrst
```

I want to reshape it so that it appears like

```
    Name  ABC
    Salary 1000
    Company xyz
    Dept   pqr
    Name   ABC2
    Salary  1001
    Company xyz
    Dept    pqr
    Name   ABC3
    Salary 1002
    Compant xyzt
    Dept   pqrst
```

Is it possible to do it in R?
I want to then write each record in a excel file i.e. I want to have 3 excel files for details of ABC,ABC and ABC3.

Thank You

Comment: if you operate this way, consider your figures will be ocnverted to string as a column has a unique txpe.

Comment: Is there any alternate way to get the records separated in individual files?

Comment: Also currently I dnt mind the numbers being converted to strings as I dnt need to do any operation on them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a ".csv" file for each table then you can achive it in a loop:

```
for (i in unique(data$Name)){

  write.csv(as.data.frame(t(data[data$Name == i, ])), file = paste0(i, ".csv")
            , row.names = T)

}
```

Alternatively use `write.xlsx()` from `xlsx` package

**DATA**:

```
data <- structure(list(Name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("ABC", "ABC2", 
"ABC3"), class = "factor"), Salary = 1000:1002, Company = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("xyz", "xyzt"), class = "factor"), Dept = structure(1:3, .Label = c("pqr", 
"pqrs", "pqrst"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Name", "Salary", 
"Company", "Dept"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))
```

Comment: I get the following error for this code    Error in data$Name : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this and if `df` is your `data.frame`, you can do:

```
data.frame(names(df), c(t(as.matrix(df))))
```